# Mysqli insert into multiple table with auto increment

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

hello i tried using mysqli to fetch autoincrement id from the first table to insert it for second table, this is my database design for each table

Table users

```
  id_user  PK auto-inc
  username 
  password
  nama
  role
  status
```

table siswa

```
  id_siswa PK auto-inc
  id_tingkatan 
  nama_siswa
  jk_siswa
  hp_siswa
  nama_ortu
  jk_ortu
  hp_ortu
  id_user
```

this is what i have tried

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users
                        (username, password, nama, role, status) 
                 VALUES ('$name','$password','$nama','$role','$status')";
$koneksi->query($query);

$query = "INSERT INTO siswa
                        (id_tingkatan, nama_siswa, jk_siswa, hp_siswa, 
                         nama_ortu, jk_ortu, hp_ortu, id_user) 
                 VALUES ('$tingkatan','$nama','$jksiswa','$hpsiswa',
                         '$namaortu','$hportu', $koneksi->insert_id)";
$koneksi->query($query);
```

the data is inserted into users table but not to siswa table, any suggestion to fix this?

edit : overlooked variable only ($jkortu) fixed now, thanks

Comment: Then, what is the error?

Comment: You might be missing value for `jk_ortu` field in second query

Comment: the data is inserted into users table but not to siswa table , it doesnt give any error output

Comment: @JigarShah thanks for mentioning it, i didnt notice, will try the code now

Comment: A bit of sensible formatting make bugs easier to find

Comment: Assuming any of these variables ($name, $password, $tigkatan, etc.) come from user input and aren't escaped elsewhere, this is vulnerable to SQL injection, and someone can steal or delete your database with a properly crafted name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latter INSERT, the number of items in the first commalist does not correspond with the number of items in the second commalist. This should throw a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a parameter.

You should always test for mysql errors, otherwise it will fail silently, and you have no idea what is going on:

```
if (!$server->query($query)) {
  throw new Exception($server->error());
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php - only a function if using the procedural style `mysqli_insert_id()`

Comment: And where is `$server` in the OP's question